# skip jsf lifecylce phase

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

How do I short circuit the jsf lifecycle so that the response is rendered before any model updates?  In the diagram of page 59 of this document JSF Spec V1.2 RevB, it shows that you can skip from the "Apply Request Values" phase directly to the "Render Response" phase.  How do I do this?  I've got a PhaseListener hooked in, but not sure if I can use it to do this or not.
Thanks,
Ben Anderson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the [renderResponse](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse()) method on the context.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

The lifecycle will skip to the response as soon as the current phase ends.